# How to convert SQLite Blob field to string with Python

Tags: python, sqlite, unicode

I want to open the Chrome (Login Data) file and use its password field. But this field is stored in byte/blob mode and can not be converted to text.

I also tried codecs and pickle and bytes.encode and str.decode but it didn't work.
Please look at the code below and help :

```
import sqlite3

connection_obj = sqlite3.connect('C:/Users/{username}/AppData/Local/Google/Chrome/User 
Data/Default/Login Data')

cursor_obj = connection_obj.cursor()

statement = '''SELECT action_url, username_value, password_value  FROM logins'''

cursor_obj.execute(statement)

output = cursor_obj.fetchmany(5)

for url,usr,psw in output:
     # convert psw blob -> ascii text
     # ....
     # ....
     # for example psw filed:
     # b'v10\x7f\xa3\x1a\xd1\x83g\x8c\xc4\x14]\xb6n\xf85\xba\xca\xf5r\x17\xb6D\xed\xf5\x11rM\xbe\xbf\xb1\xc2y\xc5Vr\xc3\xb3NB\xc7J\x14\x95'
     # 
     # convert to below text : 
     # zarfilm-136342

   print(url, usr, psw,sep='------') 
   print('*'*10)

connection_obj.commit()
connection_obj.close()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That data is encrypted in AES, and further the key is encrypted with [CryptProtectData](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/dpapi/nf-dpapi-cryptprotectdata) to lock the encryption key to user data.  You can decrypt the data with something like this:

```
import base64, json, os, sqlite3, win32crypt
from Crypto.Cipher import AES

def chrome_key():
    local_state_fn = os.path.join(os.environ["USERPROFILE"],"AppData","Local","Google","Chrome","User Data","Local State")
    with open(local_state_fn, "r") as f:
        local_state = json.load(f)
    key = base64.b64decode(local_state["os_crypt"]["encrypted_key"])
    key = key[5:]
    return win32crypt.CryptUnprotectData(key, None, None, None, 0)[1]

def decrypt_password(password, key):
    iv, password = password[3:15], password[15:]
    aes = AES.new(key, AES.MODE_GCM, iv)
    return aes.decrypt(password)[:-16].decode("utf-8")

def main():
    key = chrome_key()
    db_fn = os.path.join(os.environ["USERPROFILE"],"AppData","Local","Google","Chrome","User Data","default","Login Data")
    db = sqlite3.connect(db_fn)
    for origin_url, username, password_crypt in db.execute("SELECT origin_url, username_value, password_value FROM logins;"):
        password = decrypt_password(password_crypt, key)
        print(f"{origin_url}, {username}, {password}")
    db.close()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: You're so good. You really helped me. thank you. I want my awareness to increase like yours.

Answer (score 0):

Are you surprised to learn that this field is encrypted?  Google would be in for a world of trouble if it wasn't.  Even Chrome doesn't know how to decrypt this.  It's done with the Windows cryptography APIs, and involved your Windows login password.  You can't get them.

Comment: Really?  I did not know.  But how does Firefox import the this data into its own password database? I mean match the passwords entered in Chrome.

Comment: Firefox doesn't know how to decrypt them, either.  Starting from the encrypted data, it can use the Windows crypto APIs to decrypt them, just like Chrome.  There's a social responsibility to have the data exist in decrypted form for as short a time as possible.  There are hacker tools that can do the decryption.  Start here:  https://superuser.com/questions/655573/decrypt-google-chrome-passwords